# Mixed Integer Programming using genetic algorithm

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm, linear-programming

i have my objective function as

```
function val = fitness( X )
val = 10*X(7)+20*X(8)+50*X(9)+10*X(10)+20*X(11)+50*X(12);
end
```

and i am trying to call ga as

```
ga(@fitness,12,A,b,[],[],lb,[],[],IntCon)
A = 9X9 matrix
b = 9X1 matrix
lb = 9X1 Zero matrix  
IntCon = [1:12]
```

i am getting the following error message

```
Error using preProcessLinearConstr (line 48)
The number of columns in A must be the same as the length of X0.

Error in gacommon (line 100)
[Iterate.x,Aineq,bineq,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,msg,exitFlag] = ...

Error in ga (line 319)
[x,fval,exitFlag,output,population,scores,FitnessFcn,nvars,Aineq,bineq,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,
```

please provide an example using ga function solving mixed integer problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Ab` is of size 9x1, while `fitness()` expects the size to be at least 12x1.

E.g. the following has no error:

```
A = ones(12,12);
b = ones(12,1);
lb = zeros(12,1); 
IntCon = [1:12];
ga(@fitness,12,A,b,[],[],lb,[],[],IntCon)
```

For more information, see [Mixed Integer Optimization](http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/mixed-integer-optimization.html).

Comment: but i have a total of 9 ineqaulity constraints therefore A is 9x12
Number of variables is 12
Also dimensions of Ax = dim of b

Comment: Well i found the mistake and now its working , but the ga- is not minimizing the function acc. to my needs. i am getting a very high function value as output

Comment: can you please tell with an exapmle of specifing ineqaulity constraints

Comment: Sure, e.g. for `2x+y<=6, x+3y<=9, and x,y>=0`, see : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19090945/395857