# Matlab optimization fmincon actual function value from obj fn different from final value

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab optimization function, where the iterative function value evaluated last by the objective function is very different than the final function value. This is incorrect, see below the code for my question.

*globalvars.m*

```
global sc_element_global;
global B_j_global;
% other global variables
```

*sim_launcher.m*

```
function sim_loop
    %loop
    sc_array={0.1,0.5,0.8};
    for sc_element_idx=1:length(sc_array)
        % Set 'x' as constant array 50
        sc_element=sc_array{sc_element_idx};
        find_network_productivity(sc_element,x)
    end
end
```

*find_network_productivity.m*

```
%caller function to fmincon
function [a, obj_f, x0, optimized_exit_flag]=find_network_productivity(sc_element,x)
globalvars;    
        % Set global sc_element
        sc_element_global=sc_element;

        % Setting lb, ub, x0
        options = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Display','iter-detailed','DerivativeCheck','off','Diagnostics','on','Algorithm','sqp');
        [a, obj_f, optimized_exit_flag]=fmincon('objfunnwprod',x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,'confunnwprod',options);
        obj_f=-obj_f; % Because we want to find the maximum, not the minimum
        if optimized_exit_flag==-2
            optimized_exit_flag
        end

        obj_f   % print the final function value obj_f
end
```

*objfunnwprod.m*

```
%OBJ FN
function [f]=objfunnwprod(x)
globalvars;
    f=B_j_global*x;
    f=-f % print the iteration function value f
end
```

*confunnwprod.m*

```
%CONSTRAINT FN
function [c, ceq]=confunnwprod(x)
globalvars;
    for i=1:length(eNodeBs_global),
        B_j_global(i)=...
        calculate_blocking_probability_with_x(eNodeBs_global(i),x(i));
        c(i)=B_j_global(i)-eta_global(i);
    end

    ceq=[];
end
```

*calculate_blocking_probability_with_x.m*

```
% function to calculate probability based on x
function prob=calculate_blocking_probability_with_x(eNodeBs_global_var,x_var)
globalvars;
    % based on sc_element_global and x_var, calculate probability

    prob=blocking_probability_with_x;
end
```

Inputs:

```
% Inputs set
x=[50 50 50 50 50 50];
sc_array={0.1,0.5,0.8};

% Output set
sc_element=0.1
x=50
f=41.0172
opt_f=39.09

sc_element=0.5
x=50
f=770.43
opt_f=39.09
```

Here I can see the `f` value is way different than the final `opt_f` value. It should have been closer to the final value. That is the expectation, but I don't see such a result.

**Question**: Why the function value, `f`, inside the iteration changes with `sc_element`, but the optimized function value `opt_f` remains the same?
It looks like any change in `sc_element` does not have effect on `opt_f`, but internally `f` value is changed.

Comment: This is pretty unclear currently, try posting a continuous piece of code and comment out where the relevant outputs occur. Give example inputs, expected outputs, and a specific problem definition - "any pointers" for diagnosing "why *thing* won't work" are off topic here because they are hard to answer well.

Comment: Thank you! As I was editing this question, I realized the 'x' I pass into the optimization is really constant value '50'. The independent variable that is changing for optimization is used with 'x' in the function 'calculate_blocking_probability_with_x'. Could it be due to this reason that 'x' is not the independent variable (but expected to be one based on optimization definition) causing the issue?

Comment: It's really quite unclear what you're asking with no knowledge of your code, so I don't know if that's what's causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you. Updated post.

Comment: Is this Matlab code? `sc_element=each element from sc_array` is not valid Matlab syntax, and what is `globalvars` meant to do? Then on lines like `obj_f=-obj_f` you are assuming that the maximum is the negative of the optimised minimum, but I'm not sure what supports that assumption?

Comment: Yes Matlab code. Syntax corrected. Globalvars.m is script to save off global variables. Maximum of negative minimum is based on this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085938/maximize-3xy-with-constraints-in-matlab]

Comment: One reason for the difference in `f` value and `opt_f` could be that optimization did not reach the desired solution. The process does not state local maximum found at end of optimization. Due to this, the difference could persists.